# Zooming the screen programmatically

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I'm looking for some code which can programmatically zoom the screen in OSX. Similar to the way you can use Accessibility controls to zoom the screen using keyboard shortcuts (e.g. Option-Command-Plus Sign to zoom in). But I'd like to enlarge a pre-defined part of the screen.

Comment: main what you want? If you want to zoom any control then i help you

Comment: Hi, I'm not quite sure what you mean. I want to zoom the entire screen not a particular control. Thanks